# Magento2.2 CLI command not working for PHP version 7.1.18

Tags: magento2, cli

I have installed php version 7.1.18, apache2.4 and mysql5.7.
but magento2.2 cli commands are not working for me.
anyone can help me regarding this.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please share your errors and check magento logs

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working for me just I have configured my `php.ini` with `itl.dd` and `soap.ddl`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to reinstall the whole package, overwriting the original files:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.1-cli
```

I hope it will work.